# TCP multi-user chatserver in C

Tags: c, tcp, server

I am trying to build up a multiuser chatserver in C and have a problem catching the users pseudonym. The first message from the user should be used as his pseudonym.

I'm testing my server with telnet, but everytime when I connect its sending an unreadable message to the server and the server is not waiting for the first message from the client.

```
if (FD_ISSET(sock, &readfds)) {
            SOCKADDR_IN csin = {0};
            size_t sinsize = sizeof(csin);
            int clientsocket = accept(sock, (SOCKADDR *) &csin, (socklen_t *restrict) &sinsize);
            if (clientsocket == -1) {
                printf("Verbindung konnte nicht angenommen werden\n");
                continue;
            } else
            {
                printf("Verbindung angenommen\n");
            }
        

            //get clients username
            recv(clientsocket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, 0);

            max = clientsocket > max ? clientsocket : max;

            FD_SET(clientsocket, &readfds);

            Client c;
            c.sock = clientsocket;
            strncpy(c.name, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1); //store username in c.name
            printf(c.name);
            clients[actual] = c;
            actual ++;
}
```

Whats the problem there? Thanks for help

Comment: There's too much missing info in this question. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: For starters, TCP is a stream based protocol. One implication is that it cannot be assumed how much of the sent data each `recv` call will actually receive. The return value of `recv` must be checked to determine how much data was received and the data format must have framing so that the receiver can parse each part of the msg.

Comment: You MUST correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls like recv().  You MUST ensure that C library calls that require a NUL-terminated char array are called on appropriate arrays.  You MUST correctly handle TCP streaming - if you send 'hello\n', it may require up to six recv() calls to get all six chars.

Comment: It should be mentioned that telnet is more than just a raw TCP connection, so the "unreadable message" is likely the client providing some information about itself (supported options etc.). You should read [RFC 854](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854), as that contains the telnet protocol specification. In addition to that you might also want to look at RFC 855 - 861, which specify additional options.